# Roslyn SymbolFinder Convert Location to Syntax Node

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using a SymbolFinder to find all references to a variable.  I would like to check if this Field is assigned to outside of its definition.

```
var references = await SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(equivalentSymbol, 
                              context.GetSolution(), cancellationToken);
//Reference is grouped by variable name 
var reference = references.FirstOrDefault();

foreach (var location in reference.Locations)
{
   //How Do I check if the reference is an assignment?               
}
```

How can I Convert the location into a syntax node, and then check if the node is an assignment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`FindNode()`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Syntax/SyntaxNode.cs,1973a2affa06beb8) which accepts a [`TextSpan`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Text/TextSpan.cs,375a09d5e3906265)

So your example would look something like:

```
var node = location.SourceTree.GetRoot().FindNode(location.SourceSpan);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created an extension Method to do so:

```
public static SyntaxNode GetNodeFromLocation(this SyntaxTree tree, ReferenceLocation location)
{ 
    var lineSpan = location.Location.GetLineSpan();
    return tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().FirstOrDefault(n => n.GetLocation().GetLineSpan().IsEqual(lineSpan));
}
```

Comment: I think you could also use: `location.SourceTree.GetRoot().FindNode(location.SourceSpan)`

Comment: @JoshVarty I've been digging the blog man,  Thank's you're right that works with the reference location's location.  If you put that in an answer I'll mark your's as correct